# why are there many different ways to achieve stationarity?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, stationarity

In time series analysis, I've read two main ways to achieve stationarity.

1. difference (or log difference)
2. normalize with mean 0 and std 1

What are the main differences between the two and how should a modeler pick between them?

Comment: Ad 2): Normalization cannot make a nonstationary series stationary!

Comment: You can also try `Rolling Mean` strategy to achieve stationarity. Methods like `Interdaily-Stability and First Discrete Difference` also helps in identifying day-today patterns which gives more information towards Stationarity resuults.

Comment: Stationarity is not a thing that you *achieve*. Stationarity is a property that some stochastic processes *have*. What you're doing is trying to find a stationary process which is related to your original non-stationary process in a way that you can define a model for the stationary process and then invert that relationship. Since there's infinitely many ways to be non-stationary, obviously there are also infinitely many ways to find a related stationary process.

Comment: @ChrisHaug IIUC, the OP would like to know more about those infinitely many ways to be non-stationary, and whether there is maybe some taxonomy.